Spyder tells me file does not exist, but it does and the path is correct
I'm trying to open a .nc file with the package xarray and despite the file showing up on the spyder file explorer aand me right clicking on it and copying the absolute path to it, when I run the code it tells me the file does not exist.
Just to check I tried opening a random .txt file from the same folder with numpy and had no problem, so I'm at a complete loss.
My code is something like:
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np

b = np.loadtxt('C:/Users/usuario/Documents/Facultad/Clima de Sudamérica/Trabajo Final/Tx_1982_2018_imputados.txt',skiprows=1,delimiter= ';')

a = xr.open_dataarray(r'C:/Users/usuario/Documents/Facultad/Clima de Sudamérica/Trabajo Final/air.mon.mean.nc')


and it returns FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\usuario\\Documents\\Facultad\\Clima de Sudamérica\\Trabajo Final\\air.mon.mean.nc'
This is a screenshot of the file explorer where you can see the file I want to open and the error message:

The only thing I can think of is that there might have been an issue when I tried uptading the packages, but I don't see how.
